# Datagrid AutoGenerateColumns to display my List<List<int>> by each number, not a sum and count

Tags: c#, wpf, sudoku

or a way to display them.

I'm trying to make a sudoku and wanted to get my datagrid as a display, but it's AutoGenerateColumns displays only sum of numbers and count. Is there a way to get my `List<List<int>>` displayed in normal sudoku way?

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="siatkaGD" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="372" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" HeadersVisibility="None" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="true"/>

        siatkaGD.ItemsSource = myListOfInts;
```

Comment: not sure If I understand

Comment: get datagrid to display something like http://www.educationworld.com/a_lesson/sudoku/images/sudoku_002.gif

Comment: why auto generate columns ?

Comment: then a way to display it, without it? other than creating object containing 9 fields representing a number?

Comment: there are fixed no. of columns isn't ?

Comment: If you really wanna go the autogenerate way you would need a ViewModel for the Row -> RowViewModel wich contains 9 properties for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.) Use a Grid with Textboxes so you have full control. This is similar to a good old Windows Forms approach -> control all textboxes by yourself...

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="0" />
    <!--TODO add all your Textboxes...-->
</Grid>
```

B.) You also could use any other ItemsControl to represent a flattend list of your values. I would recommend to make a flattend list with "CellViewModels"...

C.) If you really want to use Datagrid as your View of choice than i recommend using the MVVM pattern and bind to list of "rows-viewModels"

D.) Read this article series https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Building-a-WPF-Sudoku-Game-Part-1-Introduction-to-WPF-and-XAML